# appimage-builder: AppImage successfully created but does not run on other machines

Tags: appimage

I've run through the tutorial here: https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#

Which resulted in a runable Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage file (no docker tests were run).

Initially, the AppImage works as expected. Double-clicking the AppImage from the GUI or running it via the console results in the tutorial application running.

However, two scenarios will result in the AppImage file no longer working:

- If the machine which built the AppImage is rebooted, the same AppImage will no longer run.
- If the AppImage is transferred to a different machine it will no longer run. The machine has the same version of the OS that the AppImage was built on.

Both scenarios have the same behavior. The application will appear as if it contains no executable code and immediately exit. Normally the application has a GUI interface. No error message is displayed.

Running from console:

```
tb@dt:~/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template$ ll
total 176860
drwxr-xr-x 8 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:25  ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:18  ../
drwxr-xr-x 6 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:25  AppDir/
drwxr-xr-x 4 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:25  appimage-builder-cache/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb      3430 Nov 22 22:35  AppImageBuilder.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb     13981 Nov 23 14:18  CMakeCache.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:18  CMakeFiles/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb      1808 Nov 23 14:18  cmake_install.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb       439 Nov 23 14:18  CMakeLists.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb       498 Nov 23 14:18  conanfile.txt
drwxr-xr-x 8 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:18  .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb        19 Nov 23 14:18  .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb       450 Nov 23 14:18  .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb       159 Nov 23 14:18  install_manifest.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb      6948 Nov 23 14:18  Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tb tb 181010472 Nov 23 14:25 'Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage'*
-rw-r--r-- 1 tb tb        67 Nov 23 14:18  README.md
drwxr-xr-x 3 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:18  res/
drwxr-xr-x 4 tb tb      4096 Nov 23 14:18  src/
tb@dt:~/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template$ ./'Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage'
tb@dt:~/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template$
```

(nothing happens)

gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tb/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template/Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
process 2651 is executing new program: /tmp/.mount_Qt AppVj8Ud9/AppRun
[Inferior 1 (process 2651) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

The AppImage was built from the ~/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template directory using: `appimage-builder --skip-test`

Here is the last part of the output from when the AppImage was being built:

```
INFO:root:Writing bundle info to: .bundle.yml
INFO:root:Downloading runtime: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases/download/continuous/runtime-x86_64
INFO:root:Generating AppImage from ./AppDir
INFO:appimagetool:appimagetool --runtime-file appimage-builder-cache/runtime-x86_64 ./AppDir /home/tb/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template/Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage
INFO:appimagetool:Parallel mksquashfs: Using 4 processors
INFO:appimagetool:Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/tb/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template/Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage, block size 131072.
INFO:appimagetool:[============-                                               ][===========================================================\] 11826/11826 100%
INFO:appimagetool:
INFO:appimagetool:Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
INFO:appimagetool:compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments,
INFO:appimagetool:compressed xattrs, compressed ids
INFO:appimagetool:duplicates are removed
INFO:appimagetool:Filesystem size 176580.52 Kbytes (172.44 Mbytes)
INFO:appimagetool:35.82% of uncompressed filesystem size (492966.84 Kbytes)
INFO:appimagetool:Inode table size 142021 bytes (138.69 Kbytes)
INFO:appimagetool:23.51% of uncompressed inode table size (604061 bytes)
INFO:appimagetool:Directory table size 152721 bytes (149.14 Kbytes)
INFO:appimagetool:33.80% of uncompressed directory table size (451834 bytes)
INFO:appimagetool:Number of duplicate files found 1031
INFO:appimagetool:Number of inodes 15794
INFO:appimagetool:Number of files 8380
INFO:appimagetool:Number of fragments 355
INFO:appimagetool:Number of symbolic links  6432
INFO:appimagetool:Number of device nodes 0
INFO:appimagetool:Number of fifo nodes 0
INFO:appimagetool:Number of socket nodes 0
INFO:appimagetool:Number of directories 982
INFO:appimagetool:Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
INFO:appimagetool:Number of uids 1
INFO:appimagetool:root (0)
INFO:appimagetool:Number of gids 1
INFO:appimagetool:root (0)
INFO:appimagetool:/home/tb/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template/AppDir should be packaged as /home/tb/appimage_tutorial/qt-appimage-template/Qt AppImage Template-latest-x86_64.AppImage
WARNING:appimagetool:appimagetool, continuous build (commit aaef827), build 2143 built on 2020-11-22 12:53:26 UTC
WARNING:appimagetool:Using architecture x86_64
WARNING:appimagetool:Deleting pre-existing .DirIcon
WARNING:appimagetool:Creating .DirIcon symlink based on information from desktop file
WARNING:appimagetool:WARNING: AppStream upstream metadata is missing, please consider creating it
WARNING:appimagetool:in usr/share/metainfo/QtQuickControls2Application.appdata.xml
WARNING:appimagetool:Please see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/docs/chap-Quickstart.html#sect-Quickstart-DesktopApps
WARNING:appimagetool:for more information or use the generator at http://output.jsbin.com/qoqukof.
WARNING:appimagetool:Generating squashfs...
WARNING:appimagetool:Embedding ELF...
WARNING:appimagetool:Marking the AppImage as executable...
WARNING:appimagetool:Embedding MD5 digest
WARNING:appimagetool:Success
WARNING:appimagetool:
WARNING:appimagetool:Please consider submitting your AppImage to AppImageHub, the crowd-sourced
WARNING:appimagetool:central directory of available AppImages, by opening a pull request
WARNING:appimagetool:at https://github.com/AppImage/appimage.github.io
INFO:root:AppImage created successfully
```

Comment: This may be an issue with appimage-builder itself. Please open an issue at https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/issues Thanks

Comment: Please also, make sure you're using the latest appimage-builder version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did not install an appropriate AppRun in the AppDir directory.
But the process fails without error message.

I suggest you run the AppImage with strace to see more.